# Is this a bug in open cv or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am doing a very simple open cv operations

- Read the image (with some items to be detected)
- Apply some median filter to filter out noise
- Read another image with same background but without items (a plane background)
- Subtract the background image with the image that has been smoothened.

I get two different output from c++ vs python.

C++ code snippet:

```
Mat img = imread("test_noise.pgm", 0);

Mat noise_removed_image;
medianBlur(img, noise_removed_image, 5);

Mat background_only = imread("light.pgm", 0);

imshow("Background Removed Substract", background_only - noise_removed_image);
```

Python code snippet

```
mat = cv2.imread("test_noise.pgm", 0)
background = cv2.imread("light.pgm", 0)

noise_removed = cv2.medianBlur(mat, 5)
cv2.imshow("Background Removed", background - noise_removed)
```

[image: python generated]
[image: c++ generated]

I expected that both the version should produce exactly same output

Comment: Can you provide two [mcve]s with hardcoded input values?

Comment: Which is which? In Python, you are reading 8-bit images, but doing a subtract. That will clip all the negative values as the difference will be 8-bits.  You may need to convert to floats to get what you want. Or in the other example clip the negative values.

Comment: that's integer wrapping, not clipping. you have to either use opencv's absdiff() or subtract() calls, which are supposed to do saturating math, or extend the data type before subtracting. if you subtract unsigned ints, the result is already mangled. in C++, OpenCV's `Mat` type seems to take care of the saturation on its own. numpy in Python will just wrap around for sure. you ***really*** ought to label your screenshots.